# Scale transformation of $\epsilon$ and $\partial$

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I got confused about scale transformation.

Under 
\begin{align}
\tilde{g}_{ab} = \Omega^2 g_{ab} \end{align}
And consider scalar $\Phi$ and levi-civita symbol $\epsilon$, then how
\begin{align}
\sqrt{-g} \epsilon_{abcd} \partial^{d} \Phi
\end{align}
this transform under this transformation?

First what I know, is under scale transformation

(1) $\sqrt{-\tilde{g}} = \sqrt{-g} \Omega^D$

Now I got confused with several points.  How to deal with $\epsilon$ and $\partial_a$?

(2) $\epsilon_{abcd}$ ?

(3) $\partial^d = g^{de} \partial_{e}$

---

As an exercise, based on scale transformation, I can compute $\tilde{R}_{ab}$, $\tilde{R}$ and matches up with textbooks. In their computation, It seems they didn't consider transformations of $\partial$ and $\epsilon$..

Comment: If your $\epsilon$ is normalized as $\epsilon_{0123} = 1$ then it does not scale with Weyl transformations. Further your point (3) should make it clear how $\partial^a$ transforms since under Weyl transformations (assuming that's what you are doing), the coordinates do not transform so $\partial_a \to \partial_a$.

Comment: @Prahar, Thanks.